# Did Heinlein intend to connect Red Planet with the Future History?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, future-history

I recently read Red Planet for the first time in decades. What stood out to me in this reading was the character of Dr. MacRae, who seems to get confused from time to time about his own age, talking about having seen the pyramids of Giza (when in the Red Planet history, those were destroyed long ago during WWIII), and implying that his father was around when television was invented (and only correcting himself to grandfather or great-grandfather when the discrepancy is noted by the people he's talking too). If this were a Future History novel, I'd suspect MacRae to be a Howard Family member (and thus very long-lived). Is there any in-universe or out-of-universe evidence to this effect?  I note that one of the juvenile novels is connected explicitly with a story in "The Past Through Tomorrow" ("The Long Watch"/"Space Cadet") so Heinlein had no objection to connecting his juvenile works to his non-juvenile ones.

Comment: The originally published (1949) version of the novel does not contain these elements about McRae. Gifford's *Readers Companion* says based on the revised version, "that he is a member of the Howard families is an acceptable hypothesis." The *Companion* even speculates that he is Lazarus Long!

Comment: Ah. No wonder I didn't notice those elements 40-some years ago.  This time I read the restored version

Comment: Good article on the differences here https://www.heinleinsociety.org/red-planet-blue-pencil/

Comment: Thanks.  Why don't you convert this to an answer (probably - 'evidence indicates he probably wanted to originally, but his editor had other ideas' or some such)?